# How to add class "offline" to the body if page shown from cache using service worker

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I am working on a progressive web app using service worker every thing is working perfectly. Now I want to hide some content on my pages if pages are served from cache so I need to add class "offline" to the body.

Please tell me how can I add **document.body.classList.add("offline");** in the below code.

```
//Fetch from network failed
var fallback = function() {
    if (event.request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('text/html') != -1) {
        return caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {


            // need to return the response and add class "offline" to the body here
            return response || caches.match('offline-page.html');


        })
    } 
}
```

**If I am doing wrong please let me know proper way to do it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can tamper a cached response's content. But I have an alternative solution.

`navigator.onLine` is the HTML5 API that can help you detect the online/offline status of browser. You can put this piece of code in your page:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if (!navigator.onLine) document.body.classList.add("offline");
}, false )
```

Comment: My intention is to remove the content from the page before it is shown to user. Your solution seems good, can you tell me it is more efficient way?

Comment: @Syed I would say my solution is effective. As to "efficient", in what sense do you mean?

Comment: My solution can possibly flash the to-be-hidden content before loading complete. But this problem can be resolved by include `offline` class name first, then remove it when `navigator.onLine === true`.

Comment: Regretfully I'm not familiar with the `Response` interface. I cannot answer how to directly modify the cached HTML content using that interface.